# Qmail/Plesk email help

Tags: email

Hay Guys.

I'm using plesk with Qmail as an outgoing server. I've never used my plesk setup before to send emails. I usually use my ISP.

I'm having a little trouble settng this up. I've created a simple email account, test@mycrazydomain.com. All is well, i setup my POP account in my mail client (apple mail) and i can receive mail. However i can't send any.

These are the details im using

smtp.mycrazydomain.com
standard auth (i've tried SSL and non SSL)
username: test@mycrazydomain.com
password: mypassword

However nothing has happened.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Do you get any error messages when attempting to send?

Comment: Nope. Mail just keeps displaying a "loading" image and doesn't do anything.

Comment: Administration panels are off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ISP is most likely blocking port 25. Newer versions of Plesk allow you to enable a port for message submission in order to avoid these types of blocks.  To enable this, go to 'Server' -> 'Mail' and check 'enable submission port'.

Once you have done this, change the outgoing (SMTP) server port to 587 and try again.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things you could try:

- It could be that your ISP blocks port 25 for anything but their SMTP server, its quite common. Try Telneting to your mail server and see if you get a response. If you don't your probabley stuck using your ISP for outbound mail
- Check that your mail server isn't exclusively use SSL
- Check that you can login and send using your accounts web mail facility if you have it.